# Verb an zweiter Stelle im Relativsatz

Tags: word-order

In Grimms Märchen habe ich gelesen:

> "Es war einmal ein König, **der hatte** drei Söhne..."

und dachte mir dabei, es handelt sich um veraltete Sprache. In letzter Zeit stoße ich jedoch immer wieder auf dasselbe Phänomen. Hier ein Beispiel:

> Es gibt Türen, **die sollte man** nicht öffnen.

Wann kommt das Verb also an die zweite Stelle und wann gibt es Endstellung bei den Relativsätzen?

Comment: Das sind doch nur zwei durch ein Komma getrennte Hauptsätze.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Meine Auffassung:

Es ist gar kein Relativsatz. Vielmehr wird das Subjekt des Hauptsatzes (in verkürzter Form) wiederholt: "Ein König"... "dieser  hatte..."

Begreife das einfach als eine Variationsmöglichkeit für die Bildung des Hauptsatzes. Sie dient insbesondere dazu, die Aufmerksamkeit auf das Subjekt zu lenken.

Allerdings beschränkt sich die Verwendung auf informelle, familiäre Ausdrucksweise. In amtlichen Schreiben, Zeitungstexten, auch üblicherweise in Romanen wirst du diese Bauweise von Hauptsätzen nicht finden. (In Romanen natürlich schon, wenn sie familiäre Sprache verwenden.)

Man kann sagen:

> Die Türe dort, die sollten Sie auf keinen Fall öffnen.

Das wäre ein gut gemeinter Rat an einen Bekannten in mündlicher Kommunikation. Die Aufmerksamkeit wird auf diese spezielle Tür gerichtet, im Kontrast vielleicht zu anderen Türen, die auch in der Nähe sind.

Ein Relativsatz wäre dagegen:

> Die Tür, **die Sie gerade öffnen wollten,** dürfen Sie auf keinen Fall benützen! Dahinter lauern Drachen!
>
> Ein König, **der drei Söhne hatte,** wünschte sich nichts sehnlicher als drei hübsche, fleißige Schwiegertöchter dazu.

Hier sind weitere Beispiele für solche verdoppelten Subjekte im Hauptsatz zur Aufmerksamkeitssteigerung:

> Dieses Eis, das sollten Sie auf keinen Fall essen!
>
> Der amerikanische Präsident, der hat doch wohl einen Vogel!
>
> Die Titanic, die ist schon bei der Jungfernfahrt abgesoffen!
>
> Es war einmal ein Mann, der wusste zu viel. Den nannten alle nur *den Mann, der zu viel wusste*.

Eine kognitionswissenschaftliche Erklärung für die Beliebtheit solcher Sätze in mündlicher Kommunikation ist, dass der Sprecher dem Zuhörer etwas Zeit einräumen will, sich das Subjekt, von dem die Rede ist, erst einmal richtig zu vergegenwärtigen, bevor im weiteren Verlauf der Äußerung irgenwelche mehr oder weniger komplizierten Dinge über dieses Subjekt gesagt werden.

> **Die Titanic...** [*Pause. Der Hörer bekommt Zeit, sich zu erinnern, was die Titanic gleich nochmals war*]**, die ist schon...** [*Wiederaufnahme des Satzes, ohne das Subjekt nochmals ganz zu nennen, stattdessen wird nur das Pronomen nochmals aufgeführt*]

In Äußerungen von Kindern findet man bisweilen sogar mehrfache solche "Denkpausen" in den Satz eingebaut:

> Die Titanic, das war ein Schiff, das ist schon bei der Jungfernfahrt, da ist die schon abgesoffen.

Solch einen Satzbau würde man aber in der Regel schon als ungrammatisch einstufen. Jedenfalls im Schulunterricht.

Comment: Ob Relativsatz oder nicht, ist wohl strittig. Manche sagen so, andere sagen so... *Das Auto hat eine Tür, die ist ganz verbeult* - Manche sagen, das sei ein V2-Relativsatz, andere sagen, das seien zwei gekoppelte Hauptsätze, wieder andere sagen, das sei falsch ;)

Comment: Ich stimme zu, man kann das in manchen (nicht allen!) Fällen auch als Relativsatz interpretieren. Jedoch finde ich, dass dazu die geistigen Verbiegungen und Verwindungen größer wären. Schaut man auf die kommunikative Funktion (Innehalten zur Vergegenwärtigung), scheint mir die Subjekt-Wiederholungs-Erklärung die direktere und darum bessere. Und übrigens auch, weil sie eine Erklärung für die Entstehung solcher Satzformen gibt. - Aber wenn du eine Interpretation im Lichte des Relativsatzes beisteuern willst: Ich bin gepannt.

Comment: PS: "Es war einmal ein König, der drei Söhne hatte" - geht. Jedoch: "Die Titanic, die schon bei der Jungfernfahrt absoff" - geht nicht, denn es bleibt kein Hauptsatz mehr übrig. Allenfalls als Buchtitel oder so ginge das noch durch. Aber da es im Bewusstsein der Menschheit de facto nur *eine* Titanic gibt (nämlich die, die bei der Jungernfahrt absoff), wäre auch dieser Stummelsatz-Buchtitel etwas widersinnig, anders als etwa "Der Mann, der zu viel wusste".

Comment: “Vater unser, der du bist im Himmel“: ein Relativsatz, obwohl im Hauptsatz kein Verbum steht. Oder?